# Formato fecha DD/MM/AAAA

Tags: php, date

No entiendo nada de código, vaya por delante.
Tengo una tabla en donde me sale el nombre de una actividad escolar, y justo después la fecha de la entrega.

```
<th><?php echo $asdata->name."<br>(".$asdata->deadline.")";?></th>
```

Quiero que la fecha salga como 31/12/2019, sin embargo me sale 2019/12/31, ¿qué puedo hacer?

Muchas gracias

Comment: El código es <th><?php echo $asdata->name."<br>(".$asdata->deadline.")";?></th>

Comment: Esa fecha la obtienes de alguna consulta a la base de datos? de ser asi puedes agregarla por favor?

Comment: Pues podrías darle formato a `$asdata->deadline` o podrías darle formato a lo que sea que haces para obtener ese dato. Depende de lo que quieras, podrías usar `strftime`...

Comment: Podrías darle formato a la variable antes de que aparezca en la tabla $asdata = date_create($asdata);
$asdata = $asdata->format('d-m-Y');

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema similar hace un tiempo, llamo los datos de una base de datos, las muestro en un campo de texto para modificar y usé el siguiente código para que el formato cambiara a Días, Mes y Año, adicionalmente al costado me aparece la fecha

```
$nuevaFecha = date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($row['fecha'])); echo $nuevaFecha;
```